# The Qthread does not stop after sending the terminate

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

The problem with following code is worker thread does not terminate after pressing the cancel button and def pdialog(self) does not stop until the while loop ends. I want to stop progress bar from printing the progress and hence the background process.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time

#from t6 import Ui_dialog_progress
#from t6 import Ui_dialog_file

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s


class Ui_dialog_progress(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setObjectName("dialog_progress")
        dialog_progress.resize(401, 165)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(dialog_progress)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lblFileName = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblFileName.setText("")
        self.lblFileName.setObjectName("lblFileName")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblFileName, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pbarFileSize = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarFileSize.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarFileSize.setObjectName("pbarFileSize")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarFileSize, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pbarTotal = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarTotal.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarTotal.setObjectName("pbarTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarTotal, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lblTotal = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblTotal.setText("")
        self.lblTotal.setObjectName("lblTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblTotal, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(213, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 5, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btnPbarCancel = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_progress)
        self.btnPbarCancel.setObjectName("btnPbarCancel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnPbarCancel, 6, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(dialog_progress)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_progress)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Total:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnPbarCancel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Cancel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class Ui_dialog_file(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dialog_file"))
        dialog_file.resize(101, 59)
        self.btnCreate = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_file)
        self.btnCreate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 77, 25))
        self.btnCreate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnCreate"))
        self.retranslateUi(dialog_file)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_file)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "file", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnCreate.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "Create", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class ProgressDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_progress()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    updatePD = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        self.trigger.emit()

class Main(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_file()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnCreate.clicked.connect(self.start_threads)

    def start_threads(self):
        self.mythread = MyThread(self)
        self.mythread.trigger.connect(self.pdialog)
        self.connect(self.mythread, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateFileProgress(int)"), self.updateFileProgress)
        self.connect(self.mythread, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateTotalProgress(int)"), self.updateTotalProgress)
        self.pd = ProgressDialog()
        signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()")
        self.pd.ui.btnPbarCancel.connect(self.pd.ui.btnPbarCancel, signal, self.abort)
        self.mythread.start()

    def abort(self):
        self.pd.close()
        self.mythread.terminate()

    def updateFileProgress(self, j):
        self.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(j)
        print j

    def updateTotalProgress(self, i):
        self.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(i)
        print i

    def pdialog(self):
        self.pd.show()
        i = 1
        self.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(0)
        self.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(0)
        j = 1
        while i < 100:
            while j <= 100:
                time.sleep(0.01)
                self.mythread.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateFileProgress(int)"), j)
                QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
                j += 1
            i += 1
            j = 1
            self.mythread.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateTotalProgress(int)"), i)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
        self.pd.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Main()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `terminate()` to terminate threads.

See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#terminate

> void QThread::terminate () [slot]
>
> Terminates the execution of the thread. The thread may or may not be terminated immediately, depending on the operating systems scheduling policies. Use QThread::wait() after terminate() for synchronous termination.
>
> When the thread is terminated, all threads waiting for the thread to finish will be woken up.
>
> **Warning:** This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use this function only if absolutely necessary.

There are many gentle ways to stop threads. 
For example, you can use a flag variale to inform your worker function to stop.

```
def start_threads(self):
    self.end_flag = False
    self.mythread = MyThread(self)
    self.mythread.trigger.connect(self.pdialog)
    self.connect(self.mythread, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateFileProgress(int)"), self.updateFileProgress)
    self.connect(self.mythread, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateTotalProgress(int)"), self.updateTotalProgress)
    self.pd = ProgressDialog()
    signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()")
    self.pd.ui.btnPbarCancel.connect(self.pd.ui.btnPbarCancel, signal, self.abort)
    self.mythread.start()

def abort(self):
    self.pd.close()
    #self.mythread.terminate()
    self.end_flag = True

def pdialog(self):
    self.pd.show()
    i = 1
    self.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(0)
    self.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(0)
    j = 1
    while i < 100:
        while j <= 100:
            if self.end_flag:
                self.pd.close()
                return
            time.sleep(0.01)
            self.mythread.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateFileProgress(int)"), j)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            j += 1
        i += 1
        j = 1
        self.mythread.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateTotalProgress(int)"), i)
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
    self.pd.close()
```